# getSensorList() vs. getDefaultSensor() in Android SensorManager

Tags: android, sensors, sensormanager

I'm writing a game for Android and want to be able to use the accelerometer for input.

I see two ways of getting a sensor, one way is to use the first element of `SensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)` and the other is `SensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)`.

The [`getDefaultSensor` doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getDefaultSensor%28int%29) says it could return a "composite" sensor, so if I want a "raw" sensor I should use `getSensorList`.

Any idea what the difference between a composite or raw sensor is?  Does this even apply to the accelerometer?  Anyone have experience with devices that contain multiple or composite accelerometers?  (Or some other sensor?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An update:
They have updated the getDefaultSensor method in Lollipop, and there now is a difference:

```
public Sensor getDefaultSensor(int type) {
    // TODO: need to be smarter, for now, just return the 1st sensor
    List<Sensor> l = getSensorList(type);
    boolean wakeUpSensor = false;
    // For the following sensor types, return a wake-up sensor. These types are by default
    // defined as wake-up sensors. For the rest of the SDK defined sensor types return a
    // non_wake-up version.
    if (type == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY || type == Sensor.TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION ||
            type == Sensor.TYPE_TILT_DETECTOR || type == Sensor.TYPE_WAKE_GESTURE ||
            type == Sensor.TYPE_GLANCE_GESTURE || type == Sensor.TYPE_PICK_UP_GESTURE) {
        wakeUpSensor = true;
    }

    for (Sensor sensor : l) {
        if (sensor.isWakeUpSensor() == wakeUpSensor) return sensor;
    }
    return null;
}
```

So if there are multiple sensors available for the specified type, getDefaultSensor will return a non-wakeup version (unless the default type is one of those 6 above actually defined as a wakeup sensor)

By the way, Sensor.TYPE_TILT_DETECTOR, Sensor.TYPE_WAKE_GESTURE, Sensor.TYPE_GLANCE_GESTURE and Sensor.TYPE_PICK_UP_GESTURE are hidden in the SDK, as they are intended to be used only for the system UI. There's more details on them in the Sensor.java source

Answer (score 3):

Google's documentation is way ahead of their implementation here.  I browsed through the [code repository](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/hardware/SensorManager.java) (which seems to be 2.3.1-ish source) and found:

```
public Sensor getDefaultSensor(int type) {
    // TODO: need to be smarter, for now, just return the 1st sensor
    List<Sensor> l = getSensorList(type);
    return l.isEmpty() ? null : l.get(0);
}
```

So there is no real difference (and I don't think they can really add one later) between the sensors returned from `getDefaultSensor()` and from `getSensorList()`.

Comment: Not up to date any more. See below.