# Why can't I use Sensor.TYPE_TILT_DETECTOR?

Tags: android, android-sensors

In my app, I need to detect when the user tilts his device (left or right).

In Android sources, there is a [Tilt detector](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-types.html#tilt_detector):

```
    /**
     * A sensor of this type generates an event each time a tilt event is detected. A tilt event
     * is generated if the direction of the 2-seconds window average gravity changed by at
     * least 35 degrees since the activation of the sensor. It is a wake up sensor.
     *
     * @hide
     * @see #isWakeUpSensor()
     */
    public static final int TYPE_TILT_DETECTOR = 22;
```

However it has a `@hide` annotation, so I can't use it. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27191346/3163440) from SO says that:

> By the way, Sensor.TYPE_TILT_DETECTOR, [...], are hidden in the SDK, as they are intended to be used only for the system UI.

It's really annoying as it seems to be exactly the feature I need. Is there any reason why we can't use it? Do I *really* have to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: i have same issue

Answer (score 0):

just use number 22 unfortunately. I am having same issue, but number 22 works for me.